# Изменить параметры легенды ggplot

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2

Я составила график, на котором точки помечены разными цветами в зависимости от значения параметра а, на графике мне нужно сохранить названия образцов (точек). При этом в обозначениях легенды графика мне нужны квадратики, указывающие на цвет. Но вместо этого, в обозначениях легенды получаю значок "а" нужных цветов, что выглядит довольно нелепо.

[image: График]

Прикрепляю код программы:

```
library(ggplot2)

my_data <- data.frame(Sample=c(1:12),a=NA,x = runif(12, 0, 2),y =runif(12,0,1))
my_data$a[1:3] <- 0.25; my_data$a[4:6] <- 0.5; my_data$a[7:9] <- 0.75; my_data$a[10:12] <- 1

ggplot(data=my_data, aes(x=x, y=y,label=Sample, color=as.factor(a))) +
  geom_text() +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_color_manual(name="a =",labels=c("0.25", "0.5","0.75","1"),values = c("red3","forestgreen","darkblue","orange"))
```

Как заменить значок "а" на маленькие квадраты/кружочки?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Содержимое вектора а? Приведите воспроизводимый код с данными.

Comment: [Я случайно создал две учётные записи, как их объединить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: @black_paladin заменила код на более простой, чтобы показать, в чем заключается проблема.

Comment: Теперь понятно. К сожалению, префикс легенды определяется тем, какой geom используете. Переназначить тот, который у geom_text стандартно не получится. Проще добавить
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, colour=as.factor(a))) 

и удалить вывод в легенду для geom_text (show.legend=F)

Comment: @black_paladin Спасибо Вам большое, легенда починилась:) А скажите, пожалуйста, нельзя ли так сделать, чтобы на самом графике значки точек все-таки не высвечивались, а были отмечены только номера образцов? Т.е. нужно сохранить значки точек в префиксе легенды, но не высвечивать их на самом графике

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не очень красиво замазывать вывод белым, но работает

```
ggplot(data=my_data) +
  geom_text(aes(x=x, y=y, vjust = 3, label=Sample,  colour=as.factor(a)), show.legend=F) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, colour=NA), colour="white", show.legend=T) +
  theme_light()  +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = 
                                 list(colour = c("red3","forestgreen","darkblue","orange"))))
```

Comment: @black_paladin Дело в том, что в таком случае цвета точек на легенде и цвета названий образцов на графике получаются разными. Т.е. здесь цвета графика устанавливаются по умолчанию языка R (при делении образцов по группам с помощью цветов), они довольно тусклые, поэтому мне нужны были именно перечисленные мной цвета: "red3","forestgreen","darkblue","orange".

Comment: Добавьте scale_color_manual:

  scale_color_manual(name="a =",
                     labels=c("0.25","0.5","0.75","1"),
                     values = c("red3","forestgreen","darkblue","orange"))

Comment: @black_paladin Теперь все так, как и хотелось, спасибо вам огромное!